# producing cell array

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I want to produce a cell array as below in matlab:

```
P=  {100;010;000;000;001}  
    {100;000;010;000;001} 
    {100;000;000;010;001} 
    {000;100;010;000;001} 
    {000;100;000;010;001} 
    {000;000;100;010;001}
```

where `P= {5x3 cell} {5x3 cell} {5x3 cell} {5x3 cell} {5x3 cell} {5x3 cell};`

from the 5x3 matrix, the pattern should be only one '1' in each column and the third column is '1' at final row in every cell.

i.e : `P{1}= 100;010;000;000;001`

how should I do that?

From what I had made up till now:

```
PP=zeros(5,3);
P={1,6};
P={PP,PP,PP,PP,PP,PP};
```

how can I put the ones in the cell?

thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
x = unique(perms([0 0 2 4]),'rows'); %# we'll convert 2 to 10 and 4 to 100 later
xi = randperm(size(x,1)); %# permute rows randomly
n = 6;
xi = xi(1:n); %# k random rows
x = x(xi,:);
x = [ x ones(n,1) ]'; %# add 1s and transpose
%# convert to strings representing binary numbers, then to cell array
out = reshape(cellstr(dec2bin(x)), size(x,1), n);
%# split the cell array by columns
out = mat2cell(out, size(out,1), ones(1,n));
```

If you actually need numbers (0, 10, 100), not strings, the code will be a little shorter:

```
x = unique(perms([0 0 10 100]),'rows');
xi = randperm(size(x,1));
n = 6;
xi = xi(1:n);
x = x(xi,:);
x = [x ones(n,1)]';
out = mat2cell(x,size(x,1),ones(1,n));
```

**UPDATE**:

According your comment, here is the new code:

```
n = 6;
P = repmat({zeros(5,3)},1,n); %# output array preallocation

x = unique(perms([0 0 1 2]),'rows');
xi = randperm(size(x,1));
xi = xi(1:n);
x = x(xi,:);

c = [x ones(n,1)+2]'; %# column index
r = repmat((1:5)',1,n); %# row index
for k=1:n
    P{k}(sub2ind( [5 3], r(c(:,k)>0,k), c(c(:,k)>0,k) )) = 1;
end
```

If you need the array of logical matrices just substitute `zeros` with `false` in the 2nd line:

```
P = repmat({false(5,3)},1,n);
```

Comment: Thank you.I need them to be in binary and each column only have one 'ones' in each column. with a row combination of as below:  
  
1&2;1&3;1&4;2&3;2&4;3&4;  
  
P=[5x3][5x3][5x3][5x3][5x3][5x3]  
where P{1} = (**combination of row 1&2**)  
1 0 0;  
0 1 0;  
0 0 0;  
0 0 0;  
0 0 1;  
  
P{2}= (**combination of row 1&3**)  
  
1 0 0;  
0 0 0;  
0 1 0;   
0 0 0;
0 0 1;    

P{6}=
0 0 0;
0 0 0;
1 0 0;
0 1 0;
0 0 1;